# I have json object but I am unable to access 'name' element in this?

Tags: jquery, json

This is the json data. While I am parsing it would not work. But now it works.

{
"2": {
"restaurant": "Naushijaan",
"order": "HIHUN8",
"delivery at": "11:10 AM 2016-06-18",
"type": "Home Delivery",
"name": "abc ddd",
"address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
"phone": "67777799999",
"total": "Rs 545.00",
"pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
"picked by": "By Administrator",
"date": "06/18/2016",
"status": {
"Processing": 2,
"Delivered": 3,
"Completed": 4,
"Failed": 5
},
"action": "view"
},
"3": {
"restaurant": "Aahaar",
"order": "HIHUN7",
"delivery at": "11:32 AM 2016-06-12",
"type": "Home Delivery",
"name": "sk mishra",
"address": "520viram khand,Lucknow,226010",
"phone": "6799999999",
"total": "Rs 450.00",
"pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
"picked by": "Dummy",
"date": "06/12/2016",
"status": {
"Completed": 4,
"Failed": 5
},
"action": "view"
},

```
}
```

Comment: Please show the jQuery you have tried.

Comment: console.log(data['name']);

Comment: The name of which one???

Comment: BUT there is more than one... Do you want all or any specific? Please learn how to ask question on SO

Comment: @dpkrai96 you were so close. ;) `console.log(data[0].name);` See my answer for more examples.

Comment: First I want to access single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var jsonData = {
  "0": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN10",
    "delivery at": "04:43 PM 2016-06-22",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 831.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/22\/2016",
    "status": "Waiting",
    "action": "pending"
  },
  "1": {
    "restaurant": "Jungliee",
    "order": "HIHUN9",
    "delivery at": "03:40 PM 2016-06-21",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 465.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "Dummy",
    "date": "06\/21\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Accepted": 1,
      "Processing": 2,
      "Delivered": 3,
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "2": {
    "restaurant": "Naushijaan",
    "order": "HIHUN8",
    "delivery at": "11:10 AM 2016-06-18",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 545.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/18\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Processing": 2,
      "Delivered": 3,
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "3": {
    "restaurant": "Aahaar",
    "order": "HIHUN7",
    "delivery at": "11:32 AM 2016-06-12",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "sk mishra",
    "address": "520viram khand,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9198979962",
    "total": "Rs 450.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "Dummy",
    "date": "06\/12\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "4": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN6",
    "delivery at": "08:29 PM 2016-06-11",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "Dharmraj",
    "address": "D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003",
    "phone": "7428069025",
    "total": "Rs 606.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/11\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "5": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN5",
    "delivery at": "08:17 PM 2016-06-11",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "Dharmraj",
    "address": "D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003",
    "phone": "7428069025",
    "total": "Rs 606.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/11\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  }
};
$.each(jsonData, function(index, value) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value.name));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I am using each  I get this "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2078' in"

Comment: Use JSON.parse if you are using JSON string $.each(JSON.parse(jsonData)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can access the name field.

```js
var yourJson = {"0":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN10","delivery at":"04:43 PM 2016-06-22","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 831.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/22\/2016","status":"Waiting","action":"pending"},"1":{"restaurant":"Jungliee","order":"HIHUN9","delivery at":"03:40 PM 2016-06-21","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 465.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"Dummy","date":"06\/21\/2016","status":{"Accepted":1,"Processing":2,"Delivered":3,"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"2":{"restaurant":"Naushijaan","order":"HIHUN8","delivery at":"11:10 AM 2016-06-18","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 545.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/18\/2016","status":{"Processing":2,"Delivered":3,"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"3":{"restaurant":"Aahaar","order":"HIHUN7","delivery at":"11:32 AM 2016-06-12","type":"Home Delivery","name":"sk mishra","address":"520viram khand,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9198979962","total":"Rs 450.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"Dummy","date":"06\/12\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"4":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN6","delivery at":"08:29 PM 2016-06-11","type":"Home Delivery","name":"Dharmraj","address":"D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003","phone":"7428069025","total":"Rs 606.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/11\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"5":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN5","delivery at":"08:17 PM 2016-06-11","type":"Home Delivery","name":"Dharmraj","address":"D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003","phone":"7428069025","total":"Rs 606.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/11\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"}}
console.log(yourJson["0"].name);
console.log(yourJson["1"].name);  //etc.
```

Comment: It is not helpful ,I don't know why ,I have check that

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the line end. ;)

Comment: @dpkrai96 can you be more specific ? So that i can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If it's already an object from json, just access it:

```
var data = {"0":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN10","delivery at":"04:43 PM 2016-06-22","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 831.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/22\/2016","status":"Waiting","action":"pending"},"1":{"restaurant":"Jungliee","order":"HIHUN9","delivery at":"03:40 PM 2016-06-21","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 465.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"Dummy","date":"06\/21\/2016","status":{"Accepted":1,"Processing":2,"Delivered":3,"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"2":{"restaurant":"Naushijaan","order":"HIHUN8","delivery at":"11:10 AM 2016-06-18","type":"Home Delivery","name":"dEEPAK rAI","address":"12356,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9120276440","total":"Rs 545.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/18\/2016","status":{"Processing":2,"Delivered":3,"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"3":{"restaurant":"Aahaar","order":"HIHUN7","delivery at":"11:32 AM 2016-06-12","type":"Home Delivery","name":"sk mishra","address":"520viram khand,Lucknow,226010","phone":"9198979962","total":"Rs 450.00","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"Dummy","date":"06\/12\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"4":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN6","delivery at":"08:29 PM 2016-06-11","type":"Home Delivery","name":"Dharmraj","address":"D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003","phone":"7428069025","total":"Rs 606.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/11\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"},"5":{"restaurant":"Bayleaf","order":"HIHUN5","delivery at":"08:17 PM 2016-06-11","type":"Home Delivery","name":"Dharmraj","address":"D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003","phone":"7428069025","total":"Rs 606.60","pay by":"Cash On Delivery","picked by":"By Administrator","date":"06\/11\/2016","status":{"Completed":4,"Failed":5},"action":"view"}};

// as single, hardcoded entry
var nameAt0 = data[0].name;
var nameAt1 = data[1].name;
...

// as loop
for( var i in data )
    if( data.hasOwnProperty(i) )
        var name = data[i].name;
```

Comment: It is not helpful ,I don't know why ,I have check that

Comment: What is not working? Do you even set your object to the `data` var? Like `var data = {/*YOUR OBJECT*/};`? I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is an object, to access name you must iterate through properties :

```
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
  alert(e.name);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kj0azubb/

```js
var data = {
  "0": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN10",
    "delivery at": "04:43 PM 2016-06-22",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 831.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/22\/2016",
    "status": "Waiting",
    "action": "pending"
  },
  "1": {
    "restaurant": "Jungliee",
    "order": "HIHUN9",
    "delivery at": "03:40 PM 2016-06-21",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 465.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "Dummy",
    "date": "06\/21\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Accepted": 1,
      "Processing": 2,
      "Delivered": 3,
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "2": {
    "restaurant": "Naushijaan",
    "order": "HIHUN8",
    "delivery at": "11:10 AM 2016-06-18",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "dEEPAK rAI",
    "address": "12356,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9120276440",
    "total": "Rs 545.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/18\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Processing": 2,
      "Delivered": 3,
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "3": {
    "restaurant": "Aahaar",
    "order": "HIHUN7",
    "delivery at": "11:32 AM 2016-06-12",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "sk mishra",
    "address": "520viram khand,Lucknow,226010",
    "phone": "9198979962",
    "total": "Rs 450.00",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "Dummy",
    "date": "06\/12\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "4": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN6",
    "delivery at": "08:29 PM 2016-06-11",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "Dharmraj",
    "address": "D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003",
    "phone": "7428069025",
    "total": "Rs 606.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/11\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  },
  "5": {
    "restaurant": "Bayleaf",
    "order": "HIHUN5",
    "delivery at": "08:17 PM 2016-06-11",
    "type": "Home Delivery",
    "name": "Dharmraj",
    "address": "D-242Office G 19 Sector 63,Lucknow,201003",
    "phone": "7428069025",
    "total": "Rs 606.60",
    "pay by": "Cash On Delivery",
    "picked by": "By Administrator",
    "date": "06\/11\/2016",
    "status": {
      "Completed": 4,
      "Failed": 5
    },
    "action": "view"
  }
};

$.each(data, function(i, e) {
  $("#content").append(e.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now every answer is correct.I am missing

```html
 dataType: 'json'
   ,
```

'dataType:json' in side ajax block.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a very non standar JSON structure, but, you can't access as a JSON Array, so, you have to parse the JSON to an objet that you can read more easly.

```
    var MyJSONArray = [];
    $.each(YourJSON,function(index,e){
        MyJSONArray[] = e;
    ]
```

And then you can use it AS

```
    var restarant_1 = MyJSONArray[0].restaurant;
```

And this is it!
Enjoy